# COALESCE still returning null values

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

```
UPDATE #Product_Comments
  SET #Product_Comments.Comments = (
      SELECT COALESCE(STRING_AGG(p.Label, ', '), '') + ' '
      from (
        select distinct Label, Product_ID
        from #TEMPORARYTB
        where Product_ID = pc.Product_id
      ) as p  
      GROUP BY p.Product_ID
  ) + pc.Comments from #Product_Comments pc
JOIN Product_Property p ON p.Product_ID = pc.Product_id
```

I used `COALESCE()` when there was just `STRING_AGG(p.Label, ', ')` before, and I am still getting `NULL` inside comments. If I print Product_Comments before the update, I don't see any `NULL` inside comments.

```
SELECT *, '4' AS debug FROM #Product_Comments
```

I am printing it like this. So, when I do

```
SELECT *, '3' AS debug FROM #Product_Comments
```

I don't see any `NULL`, which is weird. It means that the `COALESCE` is not working somehow. How can I fix this?

Comment: `+ pc.Comments from #Product_Comments pc` I have to say, I don't know how sql server handles this, because you don't link it back to the table you're updating. I would've expected an error, actually. Don't you mean `+ #Product_Comments.Comments`?

Comment: pc.Comments from #Product_Comments pc is #Product_Comments.Comments, and it doesn't throw an error on my side.

Comment: If the subquery returns empty rowset then the value assigned will be NULL. You must COALESCE the whole subquery, not output column only. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34f75efc1a484db63404cf93bd2e05da

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Akina said about your subquery possibly returning an empty rowset, which will produce a `NULL`. You're also turning around and concatenating the result of the SELECT right back to a potential `NULL` with `) + pc.Comments from #Product_Comments pc`.

If any part of the concatenate contains a `NULL`, the whole result becomes `NULL`. You need an additional `COALESCE` around the last reference to `pc.Comments`.

Try this and see if it works. It's pretty rudimentary, but I only had a few minutes to type it up. It should point you in the right direction.

```
SET #Product_Comments.Comments = COALESCE((
    SELECT STRING_AGG(p.Label, ', ')
    FROM (
        SELECT distinct Label, Product_ID
        FROM #TEMPORARYTB
        WHERE Product_ID = pc.Product_id
        ) as p  
    GROUP BY p.Product_ID
    ),'') + ' ' + COALESCE(pc.Comments,’’)
FROM #Product_Comments pc
JOIN Product_Property p ON p.Product_ID = pc.Product_id
```

Of course, I'd also have ask if you really need to concatenate comment back to itself in the first place?

Comment: Or you could simply remove the `GROUP BY p.Product_ID` from the original query.  That way the subquery would always return a row, and `COALESCE` would do its substitution if the returned aggregated result happened to be null.